# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) In wamp on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Nested query in Sql.

```
SELECT
   *,
   (SELECT `supplier_sign_up_id`,
         (
            SELECT
               email_address 
            FROM
               supplier_sign_up 
            WHERE
               supplier_sign_up_id = 42 LIMIT 1
         )
      FROM
         `suppliers_acc` 
      WHERE
         singup_login_id = 138 LIMIT 1
   )
FROM
   `singup_login` 
WHERE
   1;
```

It's give error-

> Operand should contain 1 column(s).

How to resolve it.

Comment: Looks like the second inner nested query is returning an expression to the first outer nested query, resulting in two columns where the topmost `SELECT` expects one. How do you want this result to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**,

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT `supplier_sign_up_id` FROM suppliers_acc WHERE singup_login_id = 138 LIMIT 1) as supplier_sign_up_id ,
    (SELECT `email_address` FROM supplier_sign_up  WHERE supplier_sign_up_id = 42 LIMIT 1 ) as email_address
FROM
   `singup_login` 
WHERE
   1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
SELECT sa.*,
       (SELECT ssu.email_address
        FROM supplier_sign_up ssu
        WHERE ssu.supplier_sign_up_id = 42
        LIMIT 1
       )
FROM suppliers_acc sa
WHERE sa.singup_login_id = 138;
```

I'm not sure why you are trying to return `supplier_sign_up_id` from the subquery.  You know the value is 42.  I suspect you just want `email_address`.